# End = Aut $\Rightarrow$ algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

It's well known that if $E/k$ is an algebraic extension, then $End(E/k) = Aut(E/k)$. But, what about the other implication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample:

The field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraic over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, but the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $\mathbb{R}$ has only the identity endomorphism (hence, *a fortiori*, only the identity automorphism).

Comment: Perhaps Im confused by notation or something else is implied here, but you are comparing the endomorphisms with the automorphisms ON the set $\mathbb{R/Q}$ - the set which is the subject of discussion - so where are you getting the trivial group containing only the identity and how is that relevant to a discussion on $\mathbb{R/Q}$?

Comment: @SquishyRhode See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/449404/11619) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411705/11619).

Comment: Hmm. Are endomorphisms covered there?

Comment: Indeed, the notation "$E/k$" is ambiguous since it could also refer to a quotient vector space. Of course, a nonzero vector space always has the zero endomorphism as an endomorphism that is not an automorphism. I have fixed the answer to no longer use the ambiguous notation.